# Ubuntu formatted drive not visible on macbook pro or windows desktop

Tags: windows-7, macos, ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd

I have an older SSD (12.04 installed on it, encrypted) that was inside an ubuntu server, this particular server is on its last leg so I removed the SSD and tried mounting it on my mac to format it, but it's not even visible for some reason. I used `diskutil` as well as the actual GUI, Disk Utility on my macbook pro, and it's not visible either. It boots up just fine when inside the server though. Also note, the server is using an Asus M2N-SLI deluxe mobo, which does not support booting from USB drives, otherwise I'd just do that - I also have no optical drive. I figured the easiest thing would be just removing the SSD and formatting it on my macbook, or even a windows desktop but in Windows (Disk Management) the drive fails to initialize.

How do I nuke this drive?

*EDIT*
I followed the instructions found [here](http://www.logilab.org/blogentry/29155), to attempt to remove the cryptswap, and now the server won't boot up at all.

*EDIT 2*
I undid my mess from edit #1, the drive boots again into linux. I removed the main user and it's encrypted homedir, created a new one and then there was no encryption on the drive. I then formatted it by hooking it up to my windows PC initializing it and zeroing it out.

Answer (score 0):

It ought to show as a disk with unrecognizable partitions or as "empty" drive in OSX and Windows.

If it doesn't show at all 2 things come to mind:

1: If you are connecting it via an USB-SATA adapter which is powered from the USB bus that may mean there is not enough power to properly start the SSD.
2: The SSD is broken, but in such a way that the server still boots, but another system won't recognize it. Rare but not unheard of.

If your intend is to just wipe the disk you can try to put it back in the server and boot the server from an USB stick with DBAN. If it's still working in the server that seems to be your best bet.

If that doesn't work either just destroy the SSD. Personally I like to use an angle grinder for these occasions.

Comment: 1) I am using a USB-SATA adapter, but it plugs into the wall and gives me SATA power and SATA->USB connector, so I don't think it's a power issue.
2) Doubtful. It operated fine inside the server, I know the user dir was encrypted because there was a .cryptfs file in the home dir, but I tried removing the crypswap and I probably mangled it.
3) Can't boot anything from USB on this server.

Comment: Honestly I think I just really messed up the disk using those commands, I tried what I found [here](http://www.logilab.org/blogentry/29155), and now the server doesn't even boot. So I guess now I'm wondering if I can recover the drive...

Comment: 1) You're right, can't bbe power. 2) (and second comment): Weird: Even if you completely borked the partitions you should still see the drive as an unformatted disk in OSX and Windows.... If you applied cryptoswap on the wrong partition you can forget recovery of the original content. That's the whole point of crypto.

Comment: I don't need to recover anything on it, I'm happy zeroing the drive out, but I can't even access it anymore. I thought the point of those instructions I followed on that link above were to remove the cryptswap. I wonder why I can't boot into it anymore...

Comment: That is why I think the SSD itself is broken. Your only option is to connect it (directly by sata, no USB converter) to another PC. If that PC doesn't see it in its BIOS, then the SSD is certainly broken.

Answer (score 0):

I think the disk is fried since its not even detected by Windows or Mac OS. You could have emptied the disk without removing it by simply inserting a Linux (Ubuntu, Redhat) Live CD.

You can still check the feasibility of the drive by connecting it back to the old state and then using a Linux Live CD or Installer CD. If the disk is being detected correctly you can still use it. If not, you'd better look for the recycle bin :)

Comment: No optical drive - as mentioned above